# How to create a one parent form having a two child forms within it?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to achieve this : I want one parent form which have a "submit" button and it should contain the two child forms in which one of the child (here suppose have two child child-1 and child-2 ) child-1 gets added to form dynamically when user click "add child-1". How to achieve this in django forms ?

Comment: Use formsets:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create form with hidden fields(child-1) and show them with jQuery after pressing on "add child-1"  button.

Answer (score 0):

If your children are of the same origin (ex. a form asking if you have chlidren; you add one child and then another), then you need formsets:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

If you want a single form to be broken in parts/steps (ex. step 1: fill in your address; step 2: provide information about your company; step 3: etc...), you need a form wizard:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/